# Openshift root shell on pod container?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

this very and really terrible not having the chance to enter root on a pods
I saw some guides but they are cumbersome and do not work there an easy way?

Comment: OpenShift is an enterprise purpose software. So, if you become root easily, that could be a vulnerability for your system.

Comment: In Kubernetes more broadly, when you typically have multiple replicas of any given pod and the cluster is free to delete and recreate them, getting shells inside containers at all tends to be a risky and inefficient approach for anything beyond debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Run with a securitycontextcontstraint of `anyuid`.

Docs: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html#managing-pod-security-policies

Examples: https://examples.openshift.pub/deploy/scc-anyuid/

Although as has been pointed out to you in the comments, becoming root in a container is unwise. There is a reason that OpenShift disallows this by default: basic security principles.